Scintilla will not Highlight or codefold in my C++
This is my code the edit control shows up , I can see line numbers , I can type text but it does not do code folding or syntax highlighting .
What do you think might be wrong in my  code ?
I am using win32 api and my program compiles well the only issue is no matter what i try i cannot get it to highlight syntax in this case html .
My compiler is g++ (GCC) 13.2.0
void InitScintilla(HWND hwnd) {

    // Create the Scintilla window
    hSci = CreateWindowEx(
        0, "Scintilla", "",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
        0, 0, 640, 480,  // Set initial size here
        hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL
    );

    if (!hSci) {
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not create Scintilla control.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return;
    }

    // Set default style
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFONT, STYLE_DEFAULT, (LPARAM)"Courier New");
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETSIZE, STYLE_DEFAULT, 10);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLECLEARALL, 0, 0);  // Apply the default style to all styles

    // Set up Scintilla for basic text editing
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETSTYLEBITS, 7, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETTABWIDTH, 4, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETCODEPAGE, SC_CP_UTF8, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETVIEWWS, SCWS_INVISIBLE, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETWRAPMODE, SC_WRAP_WORD, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETBUFFEREDDRAW, TRUE, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETTABINDENTS, TRUE, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETUSETABS, FALSE, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETINDENT, 4, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETTABINDENTS, TRUE, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETBACKSPACEUNINDENTS, TRUE, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETINDENTATIONGUIDES, SC_IV_REAL, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETPASTECONVERTENDINGS, TRUE, 0);

    // Set up the margin for line numbers
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMARGINTYPEN, 0, SC_MARGIN_NUMBER);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMARGINWIDTHN, 0, 40);  // Width of the margin in pixels

    // Optional: Customize the line number margin (e.g., font, color)
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, STYLE_LINENUMBER, RGB(0, 0, 0));  // Foreground color
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETBACK, STYLE_LINENUMBER, RGB(220, 220, 220));  // Background color
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFONT, STYLE_LINENUMBER, (LPARAM)"Courier New");  // Font
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETSIZE, STYLE_LINENUMBER, 10);  // Font size

    // Enable code folding
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMARGINTYPEN, 1, SC_MARGIN_SYMBOL);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMARGINMASKN, 1, SC_MASK_FOLDERS);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMARGINWIDTHN, 1, 20);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMARGINSENSITIVEN, 1, TRUE);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETFOLDFLAGS, 16, 0);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETMODEVENTMASK, SC_MOD_INSERTTEXT | SC_MOD_DELETETEXT, 0);

    // Configure fold markers
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEROPEN, SC_MARK_MINUS);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDER, SC_MARK_PLUS);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERSUB, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERTAIL, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEREND, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDEROPENMID, SC_MARK_EMPTY);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_MARKERDEFINE, SC_MARKNUM_FOLDERMIDTAIL, SC_MARK_EMPTY);

    // Set the lexer to HTML for syntax highlighting
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETLEXER, SCLEX_HTML, 0);

    // Set up HTML keywords
    const char* htmlKeywords =
        "html head title body h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 p br div span "
        "a img ul ol li table tr td th tbody thead tfoot caption "
        "form input button select option textarea";

    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_SETKEYWORDS, 0, (LPARAM)htmlKeywords);

    // Set styles for HTML syntax highlighting
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_TAG, RGB(0, 0, 255));  // Tags
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETBOLD, SCE_H_TAG, TRUE);  // Tags bold
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_TAGUNKNOWN, RGB(255, 0, 0));  // Unknown tags
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_ATTRIBUTE, RGB(128, 128, 128));  // Attributes
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_ATTRIBUTEUNKNOWN, RGB(255, 0, 0));  // Unknown attributes
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_VALUE, RGB(163, 21, 21));  // Attribute values
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_DOUBLESTRING, RGB(163, 21, 21));  // Double-quoted strings
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_SINGLESTRING, RGB(163, 21, 21));  // Single-quoted strings
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFORE, SCE_H_OTHER, RGB(0, 0, 0));  // Other text

    // Optional: Set the default font for all styles again to ensure consistency
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETFONT, STYLE_DEFAULT, (LPARAM)"Courier New");
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLESETSIZE, STYLE_DEFAULT, 10);
    SendMessage(hSci, SCI_STYLECLEARALL, 0, 0);  // Apply the default style to all styles
}


Setting  Lexer is a separate action afaik

Which version of Scintilla? If version 5 then your code above is incorrect, see here

Using version  550 ,what version would you recommend that would support the above code .
